# Extra HTML content on a specific browser tab

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm currently writing a feature for my website, that if a user clicks a button on the screen, it will open the website in a new tab with extra HTML content on the header. That element should be visible only on that browser tab, even the user reloads the page, but it will be invisible when the user opens the website in other tabs. 
I tried the session storage to save the condition of visibility of the content but it didn't work.
Is there any solution to my problem?

Comment: *I tried the session storage to save the condition of visibility of the content but it didn't work.* ~ post your code please... Questions that do not include code and show little to no effort at solving the issue they have outlined will likely be down voted and/or closed.

Comment: The requirement *...visible only on that browser tab, even the user reloads the page, but it will be invisible when the user opens the website in other tabs.* is hard to do with cookies or session storage, because the user can just reload the "wrong" tab. It is probably better for your requirements to add a URL parameter in that browser tab and check it with `location.href`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript cookie feature. So when the link is cliked save a cookie in the browser and when the new page loaded you can just check the cookie and load specific content.

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    const d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    let expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
function getCookie(cname) {
    let name = cname + "=";
    let decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    let ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(let i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        let c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Working sample here https://codepen.io/ympervej/pen/BaWgEoj

Note that, window.location method does not work on codepen. So you would need to reload the page manually after you click on the button.

For more info about cookie see this
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp